# How can I test that an event contains an event handler?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, moq

I want to test that class `A`'s `RegisterEventHandlers()` method registers one of its methods as an `EventHandler` for an event on class `B`. How can I do that? I'm using moq, if that matters.

- I don't think there's a way to inspect the event handler delegate from outside the class (please correct me if I'm wrong).
- It'd be nice if I could trigger the event and then assert that my callback was called, but if I mock the interface of the `A` class (and set up an expectation for the callback) then I lose the implementation of `RegisterEventHandlers()`, which is the method I'm testing in the first place.
- Mocking the `B` class's event would be the best option, but I don't see what method I'd have to intercept to do this. Is there some way to set up a mock for an event, and intercept the `+=` method call?

Is there a clean solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the invocation list for an event outside the class declaring the event - but it involves reflection. Below is a code example showing how you can determine which methods (on target instance **a**) are added to the event **b.TheEvent** after a call to **a.RegisterEventHandlers()**. Paste the code below in a code file and add to a form or console project: **Test test = new Test(); test.Run();**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class A
   {
      B m_b = new B();

      public void RegisterEventHandlers()
      {
         m_b.TheEvent += new EventHandler(Handler_TheEvent);
         m_b.TheEvent += new EventHandler(AnotherHandler_TheEvent);
      }

      public A()
      { 
         m_b.TheEvent += new EventHandler(InitialHandler_TheEvent);
      }

      void InitialHandler_TheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { }

      void Handler_TheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { }

      void AnotherHandler_TheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { }
   }

   public class B
   {
      public event EventHandler TheEvent;
      //{
      //   //Note that if we declared TheEvent without the add/remove methods, the
      //   //following would still generated internally and the underlying member
      //   //(here m_theEvent) can be accessed via Reflection. The automatically
      //   //generated version has a private field with the same name as the event
      //   //(i.e. "TheEvent")

      //   add { m_theEvent += value; }
      //   remove { m_theEvent -= value; }
      //}
      //EventHandler m_theEvent; //"TheEvent" if we don't implement add/remove


      //The following shows how the event can be invoked using the underlying multicast delegate.
      //We use this knowledge when invoking via reflection (of course, normally we just write
      //if (TheEvent != null) TheEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty)
      public void ExampleInvokeTheEvent()
      {
         Delegate[] dels = TheEvent.GetInvocationList();
         foreach (Delegate del in dels)
         {
            MethodInfo method = del.Method;
            //This does the same as ThisEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty) for a single registered target
            method.Invoke(this, new object[] { EventArgs.Empty });
         }
      }
   }


   public class Test
   {
      List<Delegate> FindRegisteredDelegates(A instanceRegisteringEvents, B instanceWithEventHandler, string sEventName)
      {
         A a = instanceRegisteringEvents;
         B b = instanceWithEventHandler;

         //Lets assume that we know that we are looking for a private instance field with name sEventName ("TheEvent"), 
         //i.e the event handler does not implement add/remove.
         //(otherwise we would need more reflection to determine what we are looking for)
         BindingFlags filter = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

         //Lets assume that TheEvent does not implement the add and remove methods, in which case
         //the name of the relevant field is just the same as the event itself
         string sName = sEventName; //("TheEvent")

         FieldInfo fieldTheEvent = b.GetType().GetField(sName, filter);

         //The field that we get has type EventHandler and can be invoked as in ExampleInvokeTheEvent
         EventHandler eh = (EventHandler)fieldTheEvent.GetValue(b);

         //If the event handler is null then nobody has registered with it yet (just return an empty list)
         if (eh == null) return new List<Delegate>();


         List<Delegate> dels = new List<Delegate>(eh.GetInvocationList());

         //Only return those elements in the invokation list whose target is a.
         return dels.FindAll(delegate(Delegate del) { return Object.ReferenceEquals(del.Target, a); });
      }

      public void Run()
      {
         A a = new A();

         //We would need to check the set of delegates returned before we call this

         //Lets assume we know how to find the all instances of B that A has registered with
         //For know, lets assume there is just one in the field m_b of A.
         FieldInfo fieldB = a.GetType().GetField("m_b", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
         B b = (B)fieldB.GetValue(a);

         //Now we can find out how many times a.RegisterEventHandlers is registered with b
         List<Delegate> delsBefore = FindRegisteredDelegates(a, b, "TheEvent");

         a.RegisterEventHandlers();

         List<Delegate> delsAfter = FindRegisteredDelegates(a, b, "TheEvent");

         List<Delegate> delsAdded = new List<Delegate>();
         foreach (Delegate delAfter in delsAfter)
         {
            bool inBefore = false;
            foreach (Delegate delBefore in delsBefore)
            {
               if ((delBefore.Method == delAfter.Method)
                  && (Object.ReferenceEquals(delBefore.Target, delAfter.Target)))
               {
                  //NOTE: The check for Object.ReferenceEquals(delBefore.Target, delAfter.Target) above is not necessary 
                  //     here since we defined FindRegisteredDelegates to only return those for which .Taget == a)

                  inBefore = true;
                  break;
               }
            }
            if (!inBefore) delsAdded.Add(delAfter);
         }

         Debug.WriteLine("Handlers added to b.TheEvent in a.RegisterEventHandlers:");
         foreach (Delegate del in delsAdded)
         {
            Debug.WriteLine(del.Method.Name);
         }


      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

When mocking B, declare the EventHandler like this:

```
public class B : IB
{
  public int EventsRegistered;
  public event EventHandler Junk
  {
     add
     {
        this.EventsRegistered++;
     }
     remove
     {
        this.EventsRegistered--;
     }
  }
}
```

I'm not certain that moq allows this, but I'm sure you can create your own mock class.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that you cannot access the event delegates from outside the class, this is a limitation within the C# language.

The most straight-forward approach to test this, would be to mock class B and then raise it's event and then observe the side-effects of the event being raised. This is slightly different than what you're looking for but it demonstrates class's A behavior rather than its implementation (this is what your tests should strive to do).

In order for this to work, class B must be mockable and the event that it exposes must also be virtual. Moq can't intercept events if they're not declared as virtual. Alternatively, if B is an interface be sure that the event is declared there.

```
public interface IEventProvider
{
    event EventHandler OnEvent;
}

public class Example
{
    public Example(IEventProvider e)
    {
        e.OnEvent += PerformWork;
    }

    private void PerformWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // perform work

        // event has an impact on this class that can be observed
        //   from the outside.  this is just an example...
        VisibleSideEffect = true;
    }

    public bool VisibleSideEffect
    {
       get; set;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ExampleFixture
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DemonstrateThatTheClassRespondsToEvents()
    {
        var eventProvider = new Mock<IEventProvider>().Object;
        var subject = new Example(eventProvider.Object);

        Mock.Get(eventProvider)
            .Raise( e => e.OnEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty);

        Assert.IsTrue( subject.VisibleSideEffect, 
                       "the visible side effect of the event was not raised.");
    }
}
```

If you *really* need to test the implementation, there are other mechanisms available, such as a hand-rolled [Test Spy / Test Double](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html), or reflection-based strategy to get the delegate list.  My hope is that you should be more concerned with class A's event handling logic than its event handler assignment.  After all, if class A doesn't respond to the event and do something with it, the assignment shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases when _Act_ part of the test is not performed on the SUT but on the dependency. And this approach should be preferred over involving reflection. This answer should have been accepted as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about unit testing, but perhaps [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) can give you some ideas. Note that the `virtual` keyword also works there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think moq has that capability - if you're prepared to purchase a tool I suggest you use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) that can verify that any method on an object was called - including event handler - have a [look at link](http://forums.typemock.com/viewtopic.php?p=5591).